# Structuring promises within angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have done a lot of reading around this, but ultimately the tutorials and guides I have found differ too much for me to get a decent grasp on this concept.

This is what I want to achieve:

> 1) Simple http request from our server  [Any API for demonstration]
>
> 2) Run a function with data from (1). [Remove a property from the object]
>
> 3) Use result and length of (2) to run a loop of $http requests to our server. [Or any server]
>
> 4) This will result in 6 different objects. Run a function on these 6 objects. [Add a property]
>
> 5) Once ALL of this is done, run a separate function [Log "finished"]

How can this be achieved using promises? How do I pass data from (1) via a promise to (2)? Is this the right way to achieve what I need to do?

If anyone can show me how this should be structured it would be immensely helpful; I have kept the functions as simple as possible for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, promises are very nice to structure solutions for this kind of problems.

Simplified solution (more or less pseudo-code):

```
$http(...)
    .then(function(response) {
        // do something with response, for example:
        var list = reponse.data.list;
        // return it so that you can use it in the next 'then'.
        return list;
    })
    .then(function(list) {
        var promises = [];
        angular.forEach(list, function(item) {
            // perform a request for each item
            var promise = $http(...).then(function(itemResponse) {
                itemResponse.extraProperty = true;
                return itemResponse;
            });
            // we make an array of promises
            promises.push(promise);
        });
        // combine all promises into one and return it for the next then()
        return $q.all(promises);
    })
    .then(function(itemsList) {
        // itemsList is now an array of all parsed item responses.
        console.log(itemsList);
    });
```

(Hopefully this is right, I did not tested it.)

As you can see, you can return values in a callback to pass it to the next then(), or you can pass a promise, and this will result in calling the next callback when it resolves. `$q.all()` is used to combine multiple promises into one and resolve if all are resolved.

Edit: I realised that you can optionally leave out these three lines:

```
        return list;
    })
    .then(function(list) {
```

But it is nice syntax though, because the separation of tasks is more visible.

Comment: This looks excellent, I will try and apply this logic to my code and let you know how I get on, thanks Jeroen.

Comment: Good luck! :) Glad you like my solution. I also really like working with promises this way, because it make the code so more readable. Just everything below each other.

Comment: Perfect. I understand it well now, thank you! Code is so much better than with callbacks.

Comment: Great. Actually, this are also callbacks. The biggest advantage of using promises is that you can chain them and pass things (values) to the next callback, or let the next callback wait (by passing new promises).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you have difficulty implementing this, but maybe `$q.all()` is what you're missing:

```
var config1={method:'GET',url:'/api/...'};

$http(config1).success(function(resultsFrom1){
  functionForResultsOf1(resultsFrom1);
})


var functionForResultsOf1 = function(resultsOf1){
//remove something from the result, assuming this is a synchronous operation
resultsOf1.splice()...;
var promises=makePromises(*pass whatever you want*);
 $q.all(promises).then(function(aggregateOfAllCallsToServer){
    angular.forEach(aggregateOfAllCallsToServer,function(data){
     //do something to data from each call to the server

    })

    console.log("finished");

 })
}

 var makePromises = function(serverUrls){

          var promises = [];
          angular.forEach(serverUrls, function(url) {

          var promise=$http({
                url   : '/api/'+url,
                method: 'GET',
          })

          promises.push(promise);
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
 }
```

Comment: It is not necessary to create a new deferred object, because an `$http()` request is already a deferred object itself, so you can just push the return value of the `$http()` function to the promises array. (However, it is not wrong to do so..)

Comment: Yea, indeed, it's a bad habit of mine to keep re-wrapping my promises :).

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand had to upvote this, finally someone like me :P

Comment: @AntónioSérgioSimões To be honest, except making async code look a bit more explicit, it's not a good idea, especially since it bloats your code.

Comment: I know, hence a bad habit. But it is indeed more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Check code below, it could contains syntax error, the important is the structure. Step3 contains multiple(6) $http requests, it waits until the last request response to return a unique response object (array) containing response for each $http requets.

```
//Step 1
var Step1 = function () {
    $http.get('api/controller').success(function (resp) {
        var object1 = resp;
        Step2(object1);
        Step3(object1).then(function (resp) {
            //resp.data is an array containing the response of each $http request
            Step4(resp);
            Step5();
        });
    });
}

//Step2
var Step2 = function(obj){
    //do whatever with the object
}
//Step3
var Step3 = function (object1) {
            var call = $q.defer();
            var get1 = $http.get(object1[0].url);
            var get2 = $http.get(object[1].url2);
            //...
            var get6 = $http.get(object[5].url6);

            $q.all([get1, get2,..get6]).then(function (resp) {
                call.resolve(resp);
            });
            return call.promise;
        }
//Step4
var Step4 = function (resp) {
    for (var i=0; i<resp.data.lenght;i++){
        DoWhatEver(resp.data[i]);
    };
}
//Step5
var Step5 = function () {
    alert("Finished");

}

Step1(); //Call Step1 function
```